# Wcf large data file

Tags: c#, angular, web-services, iis

I am trying to upload an image file in base64 format from a angular app. The app is working fine for small images but wcf is giving error of entity too large error for images larger then 200kb. My webconfig file is like this.

```
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=LAPTOP-7JC2DRGE;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=ExamDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehaviors">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web" >
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="ExamService.ExamService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="" contract="ExamService.IExamService" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" ></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"  />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I tried previous answers on this site but none seems to be working. I am using framework 4.6.

Comment: I tried but it is not working

Comment: the error message does not come from WCF but from IIS. i will tag the question  accordingly. check out `UploadReadAheadSize` [in IIS config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/serverRuntime)[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to add a binding element for the webHttpBinding binding and set maxReceivedMessageSize to something large.  The default value is 65536 bytes.

This needs to be set in the system.serviceModel node in the web.config

Below is an example xml set to 5MB

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="largeMessage" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" maxBufferPoolSize="5000000" maxBufferSize="5000000" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5000000" maxArrayLength="5000000" maxBytesPerRead="5000000" />
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Could you try updating the services node to explicitely use the binding config (bindingConfiguration attribute equals the binding name attribute). I don't think this is really required as there is only one binding but lets try being explicit.

```
<services>
  <service name="ExamService.ExamService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviors">
    <endpoint address="" contract="ExamService.IExamService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeMessage" behaviorConfiguration="web" ></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

## UPDATE

Not sure whats going on here.  I made a quick dummy service to replicate the problem.

```
namespace LargeMessageService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILobService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string EchoWithGet(string s);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        string EchoWithPost(string s);
    }

    public class LobService : ILobService
    {
        public string EchoWithGet(string s)
        {
            return "You said " + s;
        }

        public string EchoWithPost(string s)
        {
            return "You said " + s;
        }
    }
}
```

When I had a configuration without the binding defined it failed with a 413 as you are seeing.  When I added the binding it worked.  My full web.config with binding:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="serviceBehaviors">
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="web" >
        <webHttp></webHttp>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="largeMessage" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" maxBufferPoolSize="5000000" maxBufferSize="5000000" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5000000" maxArrayLength="5000000" maxBytesPerRead="5000000" />
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="LargeMessageService.LobService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviors">
      <endpoint address="" contract="LargeMessageService.ILobService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeMessage" behaviorConfiguration="web" ></endpoint>
      <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"  />
  </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <!--
      To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
      Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

I was using IISExpress and calling it through Postman by calling the EchoWithPost operation with an xml.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Hello</string>
```

replacing 'Hello' with a large string (approx 500K)

Try getting this one to work and if it does its a case of trying to work out the difference between this one and your one. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Same error from angular app 'Requested Entity Too Large' but the file i am trying to upload is only 356kb.

Comment: The settings should be used on the service web.config, after that maybe try to recycle the service app Pool

Comment: @PhilS I am using iis express on windows 10. Could this be the reason for the error. How can I change the settings on iis express. Thanks

Comment: @PhilS New error: 500 (System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException)

Comment: @PhilS It worked. The problem was in sql server but your code works fine. Thank you very much.